# Image that changes to another image when the mouse is placed over it

Tags: javascript

I try that when the mouse hovers over the image, this image changes to another one.
Why dont work?

```js
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");

function cambiaImagen() {
  img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('demo1.jpg')";
}

img1.addEventListener("onmouseenter", cambiaImagen, true);
```

```html
<div class="imagenes">
  <img id="img1" class="img-fluid" src="demo1p.jpg" alt="">
  <img id="img2" class="img-fluid" src="demo2p.jpg" alt="">
  <img id="img3" class="img-fluid" src="demo3p.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two core issues in your code:

- in order to replace the current image with another one its enough to replace the path to it, the one, that is stored within `src` attribute
- "`mouseenter`" event should be called instead of "`onmouseenter`"

here is the working example:

```js
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");

function cambiaImagen() {
    img1.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=REPLACEMENT";
}

img1.addEventListener("mouseenter", cambiaImagen);
```

```html
<div class="imagenes">
        <img id="img1" class="img-fluid" width="150" height="150" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080/?text=ONE" alt="">
        <img id="img2" class="img-fluid" width="150" height="150" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=TWO" alt="">
        <img id="img3" class="img-fluid" width="150" height="150" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00/000000/?text=THREE" alt="">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `addEventListener` you should use the event `mouseenter` instead of `onmouseenter`.

Comment: still does not work with mouseenter event

Comment: In `cambiaImagen()` set the `src` to 'demo1.jpg' instead of the background image. Then add another event for `mouseleave` that sets the src back to 'demo1p.jpg'

Comment: is in the same directory, the url is this one

Comment: I created an example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JWhite18/qs4tgawd/3/

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just change the src?

```
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var origSrc=img1.src;
function cambiaImagen(){
   img1.src = "demo1.jpg";
}

img1.addEventListener("mouseenter", cambiaImagen, true);
img1.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{img1.src=origSrc},true);
```